# How to change prediction threshold using Google AutoML?

Tags: python, automl, google-cloud-automl

After creating Model in google AutoML we can use the provided python code to make a prediction. Here's the code :

```
import sys

from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1
from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1.proto import service_pb2


def get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id):
  prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()

  name = 'projects/{}/locations/us-central1/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_id)
  payload = {'image': {'image_bytes': content }}
  params = {}
  request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)
  return request  # waits till request is returned

if __name__ == '__main__':
  file_path = sys.argv[1]
  project_id = sys.argv[2]
  model_id = sys.argv[3]

  with open(file_path, 'rb') as ff:
    content = ff.read()

  print get_prediction(content, project_id,  model_id)
```

I realize that it will only print detection result that has score above threshold `value = 0.5` . Example output :

```
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.562688529491
  }
  display_name: "dog"
}
```

How to print the other detection results that has score below threshold 0.5 (e.g. change threshold to 0.3) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the api documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/automl/0.1.x/google.cloud.automl.v1beta1#.PredictRequest)

> params
>
> Object with string properties
>
> Additional domain-specific parameters, any string must be up to 25000
>   characters long.
>
> For Image Classification:
>
> score_threshold - (float) A value from 0.0 to 1.0. When the model
>   makes predictions for an image, it will only produce results that have
>   at least this confidence score threshold. The default is 0.5.

The actual description of the field in the proto is

```
map<string,string> params;
```

So you would change your params variable that you have set to an empty dict. Change the `params` variable to : `params = {"score_threshold": "0.3"}` will work.

Comment: In the params variable.

Comment: can you give an example? something like `prediction_client.score_threshold(0.3)` doesn't work

Comment: The best way is to review the protobuf guide for python there are examples there.

Comment: Ok, I don't really understand, let's say I change the `params` to dict as you said, then what to do? How do I pass the `params` variable to prediction function `request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)` ? Where should I define the `score_threshold()`?

Comment: ```params = {"score_threshold": score_threshold}```

Comment: if I change `score_threshold` to 0.3 I got this error `TypeError: 0.3 has type <type 'float'>, but expected one of: (<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>)`

Comment: And if you change it to "0.3" ?

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for the help, I'll edit your question for the additional information